# Can I read and write key/values from ini files in PHP just like we do with .properties files in Java?

Tags: php, ini

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("my.properties"));
    prop.setProperty("name", "my name");
    prop.getProperty("name");
```

This looks so simple to set and get properties in Java. I searched for same thing in PHP, but didn't find anything useful related to this.

I've read somewhere that

> PHP can natively load and parse .ini files using `parse_ini_file()`.

As I just have started learning PHP, I can't find any code that can read write key/value pairs from .ini files in a way as simple as we do in Java with .properties files. How might I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this ...

ini files in php contains your configurations .....

the sample file ini will something look like .

```
    [first_section]
    db = testdb
    host = myhost


    [second_section]
    path = "/usr/local/bin"
    URL = "http://www.example.com/~username"
```

Now you may get the contents of this file by

```
      <?php
      $config_array  = parse_ini_file('sample.ini');
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($config_array);
      echo "</pre>";
      ?>
```

The output will be something like

```
Array
 (
[db] => testdb
[host] => myhost
[path] => /usr/local/bin
[URL] => http://www.example.com/~username
)
```

you can also get the section names by passing second argument as 'TRUE' in parse_ini_file

```
$config_array  = parse_ini_file('sample.ini',true);
```

then output will be

```
  Array
 (
   [first_section] => Array
    (
        [db] => testdb
        [host] => myhost
    )

   [second_section] => Array
      (
        [path] => /usr/local/bin
        [URL] => http://www.example.com/~username
    )

)
```

You can also save the confuguration in array as use it in later stage as suggested by kingkero...

Read more here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#78221

Answer (score 1):

In PHP I think it is more common to use files that return an array with configuration (see [php.net/include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-130))

config.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'key1' => 'val1',
    //etc.
);
```

other file:

```
<?php
$config = include 'config.php';
```